# Will there be any performance difference in following code?

Tags: java, performance

I want to know whether there is a performance difference in following two code blocks

1>

```
 if(name == null) {
    //something
    }

    if(name != null) {
    //something
    }
```

and

2>

```
 if(name == null) {
    //something
    }

    else {
    //something
    }
```

Comment: Does Findbugs issue a warning about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first compares twice, the second compares once. The difference will not be noticeable, but it's there.

Comment: +1 for "The difference will not be noticeable, but it's there."

Comment: Well, that depends on the code of course :D - if it's in a tight loop then you could double the time complexity!

Comment: @Nick: Yes, if all you did was comparing. I think the OP's `//something` may be more relevant for performance than the if statements.

Comment: Also, unless `name` is final, the first `//something` could set it to not null, in which case the two code fragments are not equivalent (it could enter both blocks)

Comment: @Thilo: if `name` is a field (particularly a `volatile` one), then you could also have the problem of other threads manipulating `name` while `//something` is running.

Answer (score 5):

after benchmarkint it on **100.000.000 iterations**, the first execution costs **719ms** and the second **703ms**.

I used a modulo so the conditions has to change every turn and avoid precompiled result. Please find the code below. I have noticed that this gap reduces when number of iterations increases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Date start1 = new Date();

  for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
    int it = i%2;
    if(it == 0) {
      double j = Math.random();
      j++;
    }
    if(it != 0) {
      double j = Math.random();
      j++;
    }   
  }

  Date end1 = new Date();
  Date start2 = new Date();    

  for(int i=0; i<10000000; i++) {
    int it = i%2;
    if(it == 0) {
      double j = Math.random();
      j++;
    } else {
      double j = Math.random();
      j++;
    } 
  }

  Date end2 = new Date();

  System.out.println((end1.getTime()-start1.getTime())+" / "+(end2.getTime()-start2.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: +1 - for benchmarking.  Could you please post your benchmark so that others can validate it / run it.

Comment: but there is a calculation. the question would be whether the precompilation is able to identify the equality of the two examples of the question.

Comment: @bertolami I am not really competent in precompilation tips, but I know that java can understand and ignore "unreachable code". That's why i added calculation instead of null test.

Comment: but at least you should substract the time it takes for 10000000 times calculating i%2

Comment: Right, I have amended this. There is still some difference due to the supplementary comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Just a brief comment to say that the compiler cannot optimize it in all cases, because `name` is visible within the first `if` block therefore it could have been modified in it, so it has to be checked again in the second `if` condition. Imagine this case:

```
if (name == null) {
    // Does something
    name = "Did it.";
}
if (name != null) {
   // Does something else
}
```

It's clearly not equivalent to

```
if (name == null) {
    // Does something
    name = "Did it.";
} else {
   // Does something else
}
```

If what you actually mean is that you should do something in one case and something else otherwise, please use `if { ... } else { ... }` - not just for (minimal) performance improvement, but also because your code should reflect what you actually mean.

Comment: +1. Use the construct that is appropriate here (and make as many variables as possible `final`) in order to convey the intent clearly and avoid subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the two fragments are not necessarily equivalent, because the first block could re-assign `name` so that the second condition will also be true.

This can introduce hard to spot bugs, so I suggest that (before thinking about performance), you think about making the variable `final` if possible and use if/else when it makes sense (i.e. it should enter only one of the two branches) and chained if's when that makes sense (for example when the first if can establish a default value for the next one to use).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there will, on the second one only one condition will be checked and on the first one two conditions would have to be checked.

An `if` clause that fails its evaluation has to make an "instruction jump" even if there is no `else` statement follwing it.

Assuming the first `if` is false, you'd be comparing these 2 execution scenarios:

```
1>
Check 1st condition
Skip to check 2nd condition
Do "something" inside the 2nd condition

2>
Check condition
Skip to "something" inside the else
```

Comment: I think you mean the other way around!

Answer (score 0):

Yes becuase both `if` cases will be evaluated in the first whereas only one `if` will be evaluated in the second.

Answer (score 0):

yes, there will be a difference: in the second example, tehre's only 1 statement to be proofed, in the first one there are two.

but: the difference in performance will be absolutely minimal, in 99% of the cases you won't even notive any difference - make sure your code is as *readable* as it can be, thats much more important ;)

Answer (score 0):

yes obviously the second code will perform inconsiderably better, because there is only one condition to check

Comment: @selvin - it is not obvious.  The compiler *could* deduce that the second test is redundant and optimize it out.

Comment: @Stephen: however, the two code blocks are not equivalent. Especially if `name` is a `volatile` field.

Comment: @Stephen most of the compilers aren't smart enough to optimize it automatically. @Joachim what would happen if `name` is `volatile`

Comment: @selvin - my point is that the answer is not "obvious" ... as you claimed.

Comment: @Joachim - I'm talking about the cases where it is theoretically possible to make the deduction.  In those cases, a compiler *could* make that deduction.  Obviously, it is not allowed to perform "optimizations" that alter code behavior.

Comment: BTW - `volatile` is only one case where the optimization might be invalid.  Others are where `name` is updated by the first "then" block, or where some other thread updates it and the correct steps are taken to synchronize ... *per* the memory model.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the compiler is smart enough to notice that the second if in the first example is redundant, so there won't be any performance change